# Image Fades Into Another, then function loads new web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I'm trying to go for an effect similar to [this](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg2/).

I want to make the first page of my website have an image fade into another image by clicking a button and then have a function open a different page after about a 2 seconds, using a timer.

I have the code for toggling the image which is based off the above example, I'm not too proficient with JavaScript, so my trouble is writing a JavaScript function that would load a new page after about 2 seconds from the second image appearing.

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you show us? Perhaps set-up a jsfiddle.net. Are you using the same code as your example?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work? What error message are you getting? Are you using any third-party script libraries? What is it that you want help with?

Comment: show us some code, please! or be more specific with your trouble

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using css animations like in the example, use jQuery to do the animation and use the complete function to do the forwarding:

```
$("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
    $("#cf_onclick").animate(
        {"background-image": "img2.jpg"},
        2000,
        'linear',
        function() {
             window.location.href = "page2.html";
        }
    );
});
```

You should also consider to put the two images in one image file and switch background-position or to overlay two img tags and fade out the first, otherwise the browser will need to load the second image on animation begin.